# Visual Studio build solution not recognizing "DATETRUNC" function for Azure SQL DB project

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-code, azure-sql-database

In a new Visual Studio project I have imported an existing Azure SQL database, to begin to use visual studio for git backups. When I import the existing database then build solution, VS throws errors everywhere DATETRUNC is used in view definitions.

Examples from view definition:

```
CONVERT(TIME, DATETRUNC(SECOND, DEREGISTER_DT)) AS [Exit Time]
...
CONVERT(TIME, DATETRUNC(SECOND, REGISTER_DT)) AS [Entry Time]
```

Error Message:

> SQL71005: The reference to the column SECOND could not be resolved.

From the error message, it looks like it is not recognizing 'SECOND' as the argument to a function, but instead thinks its a column reference...

I know from [MS support docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the DATETRUNC function was only introduced in SQL Server 2022. It is supported in Azure, and the function is recognized in a select query from VS, I can run it that way just fine, and it works in the database as the view already exists, it is only in this Build Solution interface in VS that it is not recognized.

- In VS under project settings I have tried with Target Platform = Microsoft Azure SQL Database & SQL Server 2022 settings
- DB compatibility level is 160

Comment: Is it a case-sensitive collation? Have you tried `second`?

Comment: The issue may be with Visual Studio, please report it here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report?entry=problem

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Not case-sensitive, using "second" has no change

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo copy, sent report

Comment: Thanks. They need to update VS to fully support SQL 2022 and SQL Azure latest updates

Comment: Could you please share a screen shot of the Build Solution interface in VS that it is not recognized so I can try to reproduce that from my end?

Comment: Looks like you logged this twice. I took a look at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-build-solution-not-recogni/10333180 and it is logged internally and will be fixed in a future release. Thank you, Juan.